# flutter ListView.builder make onPressed works for only the concern item

Tags: flutter, listview, card

I have a list of cards inside a ListView.builder and each card has a favorite IconButton which change it's color when clicked, but whenever i click on it all the favorite icon change their color too, i wanted to work on the concern item.
Thanks.

```
bool isPressed = false;
 .
 .
 .
onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
   isPressed = true;
    });
 }
```

Comment: can you share your item properties?

Comment: This happens because you set all your items to the same variable. You have to create a List of bools and set the corrseponding variable to true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your item you add a field isFavorite as bool type. You change the value of isFavorite and handle color based on isFavorite.

```
onPressed: (value) {
   setState(() {
    productItem[index].isFavorite = value;
    });
 }
```

For the color part you will check:

```
color: productItem[index].isFavorite?Colors.pinkAccent: Colors.grey,
```